# Wicket 6 JavaScript reference not in head

Tags: javascript, migration, wicket-6

I'm working on the migration of an application from Wicket 1.4 to Wicket 6. One page is not responding as it is supposed to and I suspect this is caused by a missing JavaScript file.

The file is present in a Java package. In the original application the file is added in a wizard step in the same package. For debug purposes *(I'm not sure the missing file causes the problem)* I moved to call to the application abstract page which is in another package.

The following call is added to an overwrite of `renderHead`. Which already contains files which are added correctly and contains `super.renderHead`.

```
response.render(
    JavascriptHeaderItem.forReference(
        new PackageResourceReference(ClassInSamePackage.class, "jsName.js")
    )
);
```

The script-tag is present in the html-body instead of in the head.

I checked that the script is present at the location linked in the script-tag. But it seems impossible to render it in the html-head.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a combination of an used `JavaScriptFilteredIntoFooterHeaderResponse`and an error in the wicket output because wicket was in `DEVELOPMENT` mode instead of `DEPLOYMENT` mode. When wicket was in `DEPLOYMENT` mode the code was added to the footer correctly and it was also working correctly.